# Remove space between lines in non gui Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, virtual-console

My system is ***x64 Ubuntu 20.04.1   (Linux 5.4.0-48-generic)***

I use a non-GUI tty, and I wonder how I delete line-spacing (set it to zero). If this is about the font, please drop a font without line spacing.

There is space between lines
[image: screenshot]

Edit:  gnome-terminal or GUI terminals are not what I need.

Edit No.2: Image from comments, as asked

[image: screen.window_width()/2, screen.window_height()/2]

Edit No.3: Screenshot of pseudo-gui for @xiota. These are colored symbols (using \x1b[...m)[image]

Comment: TTY console spacing is usually already set to 1, as shown in your second image... but in your question, you say you want spacing to be 0. So I still don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to set the spacing to the minimal possible value. Imagine line spacing is 0.001, so the lines follow each other nearly without any space. That's what I want to do. You see, line spacing 2.0 has a bigger space between lines than 1. So I want it to be the smallest possible value—something like no spacing at all (If it's possible).

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?  (The reason you want to do this.)  The space between lines is to prevent the descending part of letters like 'g' from crashing into the top of letters like 'X'.  On my computer, there are only three pixels between them. // You can try the options at `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.  If that doesn't help, you'll have to search for how to make your own console font.

Comment: I am creating a pseudo-gui, and I need to output a lot of colored spaces at different lines. That's why I need no line spacing.

Comment: Do you have an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think so. I can send a screenshot from gnome-terminal, where it's displayed kinda well

Comment: So you really just need boxes that connect to each other. Not really anything to do with line spacing?

Comment: The problem is in non-gui it's displayed not correct. Line spacing divides colored spaces between each other so that I have a black line between each row of symbols. That's looking quite bad.

Comment: Did you try changing the console fonts with `dpkg-reconfigure` ?